# Get value from select2 multiselect and write them in a Model property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

This is my views where I have a multiselect dropdownlist:

```
    @model Model.FilterPresenter
    
                <div class="col-sm-1" style="display: inline-block">
                    <label class="individua-filter-name">Departement</label>
                    <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.DepFilter.SelectedValue, Model.DepFilter.Values,
 new {id = "DepFilter", @multiple = "true"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            multiselectFunction($('#DepFilter'), 90);
    
            $("button").css('text-shadow', 'none');
        });
    
        function multiselectFunction(element, size) {
            element.multiselect({
                disableIfEmpty: true,
                disabledText: ' -- ',
                maxHeight: 200,
                buttonWidth: '' + size + 'px',
                onChange: function () {
                    var selectEle = element.find("option:selected");
                    if (selectEle.length > 0) {
                        element.next().find("button").addClass('selectedFilter');
                    }
                    else {
                        element.next().find("button").removeClass('selectedFilter');
                    }
                },
                nonSelectedText: 'None',
                allSelectedText: 'All',
                numberDisplayed: 2,
                onSelectedText: 'Selected'
            });
        }
    
    </script>
```

This is the FilterPresenter class:

```
public class FilterPresenter
    {
        public FilterPresenter(List<SelectListItem> values, string selectedValue)
        {
            this.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
            this.Values = values;
        }

        public FilterPresenter()
        {
            this.SelectedValue = null;
            this.Values = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }

        public string SelectedValue { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> Values { get; set; }

        public string[] multipleSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

Here I saw that it is possible to recover such values:
https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/e5tg5kLr/

The question is it possible to retrieve the ids of the selected elements and then enhance them in my multipleSelected property?

Comment: In the code you posted you're not using select2, I'm not sure I understand what your problem is?

Comment: Yes, I use it ... I haven't reported all the code on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, what you really need to know is:

#### **How to render a C# object for later use in js code**.

1. Define a function in `FilterPresenter`. This function will return a serialized string of `Values`:

```cs
// using Newtonsoft.Json;
// using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

public string GetSerialized()
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        this.Values, 
        Formatting.None, 
        new JsonSerializerSettings {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, 
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        }
    );
}
```

2. If using `@Html.DropDownListFor()` is not a must, don't use it. The example jsFiddle you provided (https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/e5tg5kLr/) is your starting point. If you must use `@Html.DropDownListFor()`, see point no. 3.

In your HTML:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="test" />
```

In your `<script>` tag:

```js
var list = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.GetSerialized())'); // <-- this line is the key
```

- `Model.GetSerialized()` returns a C# string (of the serialized values).
- `Html.Raw()` renders the string in **raw html**.
- A pair of `'` to make the result as a proper js string.
- `JSON.parse()` parses the **serialized json string** into a **js array**.

Once you find the way to convert your C# object to a js object, you can use it in your js code. In this example, you nedd to pass it as one of the options in `select2`:

```js
$('#test').select2({
    data: list,
    multiple: true
});
```

3. If you must render the dropdown using `@Html.DropDownListFor()`, you need to get the selected ids of your dropdown list and match with the js object created by a C# object. Now you can back to point 2. and see the js code on how this can be done.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/bemnlam/0a72caa4f0f117c60b46fdb0bcfb4c14) contains a minimal MVC example illustrating the points mentioned above.

Good luck!